# points are drawn on main window not on the label in the GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5

i'm loading an image on a label supposed after that 
a mouse click event that draws dots on the label but dots are drawn on the main window ( behind the label )

[GUI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIgH0.png)

```
    class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)
            self.setFixedSize(self.size())
            self.show()
            self.points = QtGui.QPolygon()

            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.points << e.pos()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 5)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(brush)
        for i in range(self.points.count()):
            # qp.drawEllipse(self.points.point(i), 5, 5)
            # or
            qp.drawPoints(self.points)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `QPainter(self)` so the paint device is the MainWindow. Instead call QPainter on the QPixmap. Here is an example.

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.pix = QPixmap('photo.jpeg')
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0)
        self.points = QPolygon()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.points << QPoint(event.x() - self.lbl.x(), event.y() - self.lbl.y())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self.pix)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        pen = QPen(Qt.red, 5)
        brush = QBrush(Qt.red)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(brush)
        qp.drawPoints(self.points)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
```

However a better way is to use QImage in a custom widget that will act as a canvas.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Canvas(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, photo, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.image = QImage(photo)
        self.setFixedSize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            qp = QPainter(self.image)
            qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5))
            qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
            qp.drawPoint(event.pos())
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        rect = event.rect()
        qp.drawImage(rect, self.image, rect)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        w = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        grid = QGridLayout(w)
        grid.addWidget(Canvas('photo.jpeg'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the co ordinates of those and store them in a variable ?

Comment: @HassanKhaledBosha Sure, just append the point to a list in the mousePressEvent.

Comment: when i loaded the image it took the whole main window instead of just showing on the label in the GUI